# Determining due date (with hours) with Start date, length in hours and business hours in salesforce formula

Tags: formula, date

On the case Standard object, i would like to determine the due date when the case is created. Business hours is active (9AM to 6PM, monday to friday, no exception, no holiday),and i've got Different durations of intervention for every customer.
So, i know createdDate (date/hours), duration__c(number 2,2) and i need a formula to determine DueDate__c with no APEX code.
Is it possible? Thanks a lot.